# Displaying QWidgets created with QWebPluginFactory

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

Based on Qt 4.5.1
I placed QWidget, created with QWebPluginFactory, into HTML page.

...



...

TestObject works just fine, also JS communication with it. But i found two problems:

1. I cant draw no HTML elements above QWidget(positioning absolute and setting z-indexes). Is there any way how to set rendering order in WebKit? Or to make z-index work ? Changing width, height and other properties works just fine.
2. When i hide parent div for testObj (display:none) and show it again(display:block), WebPluginFactory is called again and original object is destroyed. (Currently my workaround is to resize TestObj to 1 * 1 pixels, so user doesnot sees it).

Does anybody knows how this works exactly? Is something of this fixed in 4.6 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with 4.7 release. It looks like it is still not fixed just yet: check [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34415https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34415)